# A possessive affix for words ending in 've'?

Tags: possessives, dictionaries, affixes

I was playing with my spell-checker, and decided to download up-to-date English (British) dictionaries from [there](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice).

One of the files that is essential for spell-checkers, in addition to the `.dic` files which stores the dictionary itself, is the `.aff` file which stores all possible affixes. More about the format of this file can be found [here](https://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/affix.readme), and I pasted the list of affixes for the language `en_GB` [here](https://pastebin.com/ff146fTp).

Now the question. My spell-checker doesn't seem to accept the possessive form:

> the objecti**ve's** gradient

and indeed, I cannot find the corresponding rule in the affix file (there is no match for `e's` in that file). I have never heard anyone complain about this spelling before though, and I am wondering if this is the correct British spelling? If so, maybe someone would have an insight about how to add the corresponding rule to the affix file?

In comparison, the list of affixes for the language `en_US` (American English, pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/v2RTnEwf)) is much shorter, and does contain a simple rule for the possessive `'s` (cf line 105).

Comment: It would be good to know why this was downvoted?

Comment: Virtually all spell checkers are broken.  Asking why a spell checker rejects a valid spelling is a question for other boards, not EL&U.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow or SuperUser.

Comment: I downvoted for lack of research effort. You say that one spell-checker objects to "objective's". What does your ear tell you? Have you checked any usage guides or textbooks to see what they have to say about how to form and spell the genitive/possessive form of a noun in English? Have you searched for examples of "objective's" being used online?

Comment: Sorry if this question was unusual for this forum. I hesitated before posting it here, but it was more of a linguistic issue, rather than a technical (I roughly understand the file format) or usage one (I understand the spell-checker configuration and output). @sumelic: I am a non-native, so I don't rely on my ears too much; and as I said I was looking for some insight about the grammatical rules leading to the result obtained, not about the result itself. Arguably I could have found this in a textbook, but I think that's the point of a forum?

Comment: @Sheljohn I would imagine that your spell checker thinks that *objective* is an adjective and that it should be *the objective gradient*.

Comment: @Araucaria That could be an excellent explanation too, but I don't think it is "smart" enough for syntactic analysis (there are no sentence-level corrections).

Comment: @Sheljohn That's a noun phrase correction (not a sentence level one)  :) You could try *the blue's tinge*, or something like that, and see where it gets you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not actually a spelling issue, but rather a supposed grammar issue: many people believe (against all evidence) that only animate nouns have possessive forms. They would argue for "the gradient of the objective". (And truth be told, I do find "the objective's gradient" a bit awkward, though it might well sound better in context.)

Comment: I think that an opinionated curator at Apache is more likely than an omission in this case. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why?

Comment: FYI, that wasn't me